# Place background image on the right of the dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a dropdown menu.

[image]

I want to move my icons to the far right. I've tried

```
 if (item.logo) {
    result.find("a")
      .addClass("ui-menu-item-icon")
      .css("background-image", "url(" + item.logo + ")")
      .css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat')
      .css('background-position', 'top right')
      .css('background-size', '28px 19px');
  }
```

I couldn't seem to make it work.

Here is my

## [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/4sv3cpeu/)

Any hints ?

Comment: I can see them fine, on the actual JS fiddle site. See this [image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/Screen%20Shot%202016-03-03%20at%209.12.22%20AM.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS

```
.ui-menu-item-icon {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Work like a dream ! .. You save my life, mate :)

Comment: Nice and simple. May I ask, how do you know that `.ui-menu-item-icon` ?

Comment: It's the jQuery ui class on your links. Links are by default inline. So with a display block attribute, they takes 100% width. This way you can define your background image position to the right.

Answer (score 0):

If your `a` elements are in a list, try adding a width to both of them. In this case I assume your `dropdown` element (list item's parent) has a fixed width, so adding a `width: 100%;` should do the trick. For example:

```css
li {
  width: 100%;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100;
}
```

The `a` element needs to be *displayed as a block* to be given a size.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can try

1. Add padding at right side so your image moves a little further.
2. Make your link display: block; not sure if it will work. Wont if image is not in flow.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS, to make the icons appear right after the text.

```
a.ui-menu-item-icon {
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4sv3cpeu/2/

**Other option:**

Add this to make the Icons appear on the far right end of the option

```
a.ui-menu-item-icon {
    display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4sv3cpeu/4/

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
li a {
  display: block;
}
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/s75o5xo6/